# Importing CSV of arrays as list

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to do the following:

I have a .csv file with N rows and 2 columns that I need to import and convert to a list.

Example file from .csv:

[First seven rows of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8WDU.png)

I import with command: `points <- read.csv("points.csv")`

```
'data.frame':   42 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Firefly     : int  0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ Hawkes_times: Factor w/ 42 levels "[ 0.03485687  0.20167375  0.20275073
```

I need it as a sorted "List of 2" (one for each Firefly) with the following structure:

```
> str(points)
List of 2
 $ : num [1:33] 0.79 0.87 0.88 0.89 0.94 1.01 1.13 1.19 ...
 $ : num [1:14] 0.00 0.10 0.56 0.67 1.27 1.31 1.37 1.42 ...
```

, where the first list represents Firefly == 0 and second list represents Firefly == 1.

I attempt the following:

```
fy0 <- subset(points,Firefly == 0)
fy1 <- subset(points,Firefly == 1)
points.list <- list(fy0,fy1)

> str(points.list)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   21 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Firefly     : int [1:21] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ Hawkes_times: Factor w/ 42 levels "[ 0.03485687  0.20167375  0.20275073  0.20941455  0.40515277  0.47026309\n  0.55714817  0.64789982  0.70749241 "| __truncated__,..: 30 29 28 31 39 40 33 37 25 24 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   21 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Firefly     : int [1:21] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ Hawkes_times: Factor w/ 42 levels "[ 0.03485687  0.20167375  0.20275073  0.20941455  0.40515277  0.47026309\n  0.55714817  0.64789982  0.70749241 "| __truncated__,..: 26 32 21 23 20 41 34 22 27 36 ...
```

I think I need a `as.numeric(fy0$Hawkes_times)` somewhere, but I want to avoid loops since I will have hundreds of rows and n Firefly values (fy0, fy1, fy2, ... fyn).

Thank you!

-Richard

Answer (score 1):

```r
points <- data.frame(firefly=rep(0:1, times=10), times=1:20)
split(points$times, points$firefly)
# $`0`
#  [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
# $`1`
#  [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

This does not rely on equally-sized groups:

```r
set.seed(42)
points <- data.frame(firefly=sample(0:1, size=20, replace=TRUE), times=1:20)
split(points$times, points$firefly)
# $`0`
# [1]  3  8 11 14 15 18 19
# $`1`
#  [1]  1  2  4  5  6  7  9 10 12 13 16 17 20
```

and as you can see the order is preserved.